# Is there a way to use input data to search through an API response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am current working on a web application that when you input your search data and click push search, it will retrieve the data from the api. I was hoping someone can help me by showing me how to use the user input in order to map the response based on the user input and render in on the screen. Nothing is rendering

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../App.css'
import GasStationList from './GasStationsList'

 class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    
      this.state = {
        initialStations: [],
        stations: [],
        search: ''
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      axios.get('http://api.eia.gov/series/?api_key=9b0550c7825c207680e9b8bcc661f666&series_id=TOTAL.MGUCUUS.M')
     .then(response => {
       this.setState({initialStations: response.data});
       console.log(response)
     }).catch(error =>{
        console.log(error)
        this.setState({
          errorMsg: 'Error Retriving Data'
        })
      }); 
    }

    handleSearchChange = value => {
   const stationsFiltered = this.state.initialStations.filter(initialStation => initialStation.name.includes(value));
   this.setState({stations: stationsFiltered, search: value});
   console.log(this.state.filter)
  }
  

  clickHandler = () => {
      this.setState({
        stations: this.state.stationsFiltered
      }) 
    } 

  render(){
    return ( 
      <div>
        <div className='search-container'>
          <label> Station Search </label>
          <input 
            type='text' 
            name='search'
            value={this.search} 
            onChange={this.handleSearchChange} 
          />
        </div>

        <button 
            onClick={() => this.clickHandler()} 
            className='Search-Button'>
            Search
        </button>

          <GasStationList stations={this.state.stations}/>
         
      </div>
    )
  }
  
}
export default Search;
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code-only questions. Enrich your question with actual sentences.

Comment: ok thank you I will make sure to do so next time.

Comment: and the filtering function should be applied to which `stations` attribute? `name`, `id`...?

Comment: the filtering function should apply to the _id. I am current working on a web application that when you input your search data and click push search, it will retrieve the data from the api. I was hoping someone can help me by showing me how to use the user input in order to map the response based on the user input and render in on the screen. Nothing is rendering

Comment: Why wait until “next time”? You can [edit] this question now!

Comment: I edit the question with more detail explanations. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that `stations` objects have a property called `name` to be filtered, you could use `filter` function every time input value changes. Something like:

```
handleSearchChange = value => {
   const stationsFiltered = this.state.station.filter(stat => stat.name.includes(value));
   this.setState({stations: stationsFiltered, search: value});
}
```

Note that this solutions overrides `stations` every time you made a search. This is not good (every time you have to re-fetch all the unfiltered `stations`).

Why don't you store initial `stations` and then filter them saving search result in another state variable. Something like:

```
class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    
      this.state = {
        initialStations: [],
        stations: [],
        search: ''
      }
    }

    handleSearchChange = value => {
      // now we are filtering always initialStations and store data filtered in stations
      const stationsFiltered = this.state.initialStations.filter(stat => stat.name.includes(value));
      this.setState({stations: stationsFiltered, search: value});
  }
  

  clickHandler = () => {
    axios.get('http://api.eia.gov/series/?api_key=9b0550c7825c207680e9b8bcc661f666&series_id=TOTAL.MGUCUUS.M')
     .then(response => {

       this.setState({initialStations: response.data, stations: response.data});
       console.log(response)


     }).catch(error =>{
        console.log(error)
        this.setState({
          errorMsg: 'Error Retriving Data'
        })
      });      
    } 

  render(){
    return ( 
      <div>
        <div className='search-container'>
          
          <label> Station Search </label>
          <input 
            type='text' 
            name='search'
            value={this.state.search} 
            onChange={this.handleSearchChange} 
          />

        </div>

        <button 
            onClick={() => this.clickHandler()} 
            className='Search-Button'>
            Search
          </button>
          <GasStationList />
          <div key={this.series_id}>this the gas stations{`${this.state.data} ${this.state.series_id}`}
          and their Id
          </div>
          {this.state.stations}
         
      </div>
    )
  }
  
}
export default Search;
```

But there is another problem. You could say "if value is empty, I want to show all the stations". To do that, you should change `handleSearchChange` in this way:

```
  handleSearchChange = value => {
      if (value === '') {
         this.setState({stations: initialStations, search: value});
      }
      else {
         const stationsFiltered = this.state.initialStations.filter(stat => stat.name.includes(value));
         this.setState({stations: stationsFiltered, search: value});
      }
  }
```

**EDIT**

After you change code I see that you are using `this.state.stationsFiltered` in `clickHandler` but `stationsFiltered` is not on state. From your code I also see that you want a behaviour like that:

1. I make a search (writing something on `input`);
2. Then I click `button` and `stations` are shown;

Ok so I suggest something like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../App.css'
import GasStationList from './GasStationsList'

 class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    
      this.state = {
        initialStations: [],  //<-- this is the entire list of available stations (from fetch)
        stations: [], //<-- this is the array with all the filtered stations
        search: ''
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      axios.get('http://api.eia.gov/series/?api_key=9b0550c7825c207680e9b8bcc661f666&series_id=TOTAL.MGUCUUS.M')
     .then(response => {
       this.setState({initialStations: response.data});
       console.log(response)
     }).catch(error =>{
        console.log(error)
        this.setState({
          errorMsg: 'Error Retriving Data'
        })
      }); 
    }

    handleSearchChange = value => {
      // here we just set the seach value with what you typed on input
      this.setState({search: value});
    }
  

  clickHandler = () => {
      // here we filter initialStations on name property using this.state.search
      const stationsFiltered = this.state.initialStations.filter(initialStation => initialStation.name.includes(this.state.search));
      this.setState({
        stations: stationsFiltered 
      }) 
    } 

  render(){
    return ( 
      <div>
        <div className='search-container'>
          <label> Station Search </label>
          <input 
            type='text' 
            name='search'
            value={this.state.search} // <-- note: here is this.state.search (in your code is written this.search and is not correct)
            onChange={this.handleSearchChange} 
          />
        </div>

        <button 
            onClick={() => this.clickHandler()} 
            className='Search-Button'>
            Search
        </button>

          <GasStationList stations={this.state.stations}/>
         
      </div>
    )
  }
  
}
export default Search;
```

Comment: Hi Giovanni, so I tried the code but its telling me  Search.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
 at Search.handleSearchChange (Search.js:18).  I want the search input to be able to handle zip code as well as strings, then render it base on the search input.

Comment: @Bojurie what solution you selected? The last one with `initialStations`? If yoes, did you initialize `initialStations` in constructor inside `this.state`?

Comment: no I selected the first one because I felt like rendering all stations will be too many. so the initial state should be empty and when you enter your search input then it should filter our data base on your query and render accordingly

Comment: "so the initial state should be empty" so this means that at startup `this.state.stations` is empty?

Comment: yes or I was thinking 1. at start up, when componentDidMont we can axios.get the data. 2nd upon search input it can be filtered to the correct search. 3rd upon clicking the button, clickHandler will render what you are searching for. Sorry I am just trying to make the flow as clear as I can

Comment: Yes correct. `componentDidMont` you store your station in qnother state variable. Then on filtering, you get this state variable, filter and set `this.state.stations` with filter result. Should work.

Comment: ok thank you so much I was able to alter the code but when I tried to filter it to render on the UI, I get an error on the console stating the FILTER is not a function.                      handleSearchChange = value => {
   const stationsFiltered = this.state.initialStations.filter(initialStation => initialStation.name.includes(value));
   this.setState({stations: stationsFiltered, search: value});
   console.log(this.state.filter)
  }
  

  clickHandler = () => {
      this.setState({
        stations: this.state.stationsFiltered
      }) 
    }

Comment: I'm a little bit lost. Let's do this: update your question with current code and I will update my answer with the solution (if I found it =))

Comment: ok I have update my code Giovanni. Thank you for taking a look at it

Comment: @Bojurie I updated my answer. I hope is what you are looking for =)